# Connecting Java to MySQL - Package does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, jar, package

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and have followed many instruction but to no avail.

I am trying to connect my program up with my MySQL database, I have install the MySQL driver, or at least I think I have, I have added it to the class path, then I also installed it as a user library.

Then when I compile it through the command line I get an error:
error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist

I even downloaded an earlier version of the driver jar and this did not work, I have spent probably a solid 8 hours trying to figure this out

My code:

```
String[] settings = new String[10];

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("settingsFile.txt");
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        for(int i=0; i <=9; i++){
                settings[i] = textReader.readLine();
            }

        textReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to connect to database.\nSettings file Not Found");
    }

    String host = settings[2];
    String uName = settings[3];
    String uPass = settings[4];

    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection to database established");
    }
    catch ( SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException err ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage( ) + "\n\nDid not connect.");
    }

}
```

Please help, I think I am going grey over this.

Comment: *I am trying to connect my script* - what script?

Comment: Where did you place the MySQL connector JAR?  How are you building and running your program?

Comment: please share the full stack-trace of your exception and it would be helpful.

Comment: The name of the jar file is mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar,
I am using Eclipse, the Jar in in a folder within the project folder.

Comment: I am self taught and still fairly new to Java, I'm sorry I don't know what that is.

Comment: It is in there. I've added, removed and re-added it more times than I can remember, and nothing helps.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse then why are you trying to compile from the command line?

Comment: Is the MySQL JAR on your Eclipse classpath?

Comment: Because that is what I am most comfortable with.

Comment: I'm not sure about the class path.

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName(driver).newInstance()` line since 2007. Where are you importing the `com.mysql.jdbc` package? and why?

Comment: *Because that is what I am most comfortable with* well in Eclipse do you have any red swiggly lines that shows that it is not compiled?

Comment: No red squiggly lines what so ever.

Comment: so just run it from Eclipse.  Eclipse auto-compiles your code for you, you do not need to re-compile it from the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only get this error if you have

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.*;
```

or one or more specific imports from that package.

Solution: remove it. You don't need it. You should only be importing from `java.sql`.

NB You haven't needed the `Class.forName(driver).newInstance();` line since 2007.

Comment: So I should remover the whole line of the `Class.forName(driver).newInstance();` aswell?

Comment: As I've already told you that you haven't needed it since 2007, it is difficult to see why you're even asking.

Comment: Okay so now it is giving the error message of No suitable driver install.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Removing the import of the non-existent package will remove the error message about the non-existent package. Clearly you have not even read my answer.

Comment: @HaydenKennedy So the MySQL Connector JAR file isn't on the CLASSPATH when you run the program.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Removing the import fixes his problem compiling from the command line, which is what the question is actually about. The import is not necessary and should be removed regardless of how he is compiling the program. The OP has now got to 'no suitable driver installed', which is an exception, i.e. thrown at runtime, which means he has now succeeded in compiling the code. QED.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I answered the question he asked, and the subsequent one about 'no suitable driver'. If he does everything I've told him he has solved all the problems he has stated. Difficult to see what more I can do. You on the other hand have perpetrated numerous erroneous statements that you should now delete. And some some clown has downvoted this correct answer, which is more a reflection on them than anything else.

Comment: @ScaryWombat As you've now removed them, I can only assume you agree, whatever your last comment may mean.

Comment: @EJP I have tried with the Javac -classpath but all I get is 'no source files'

Comment: @ScaryWombat I shall take your advise and just run it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by not including

```
import com.mysql.cj.util.StringUtils; 
import java.mysql.*;
```

I also created a class StringUtils.java in my controller.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your compile command? Did you mean javac? Maybe you should specify classpath to enable jvm find mysql related class files.

just like

```
javac -classpath "jar file locations" YourJavaFile.java
```

Answer (score -2):

First things first:
You will want to check if the driver for MySQL is added as a Library or as a JAR ,
you want to have it as a Jar.

you will need to have this packages import at least:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

you don't need the:

```
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

you can just do:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

also in your code I am not sure if you are making a request to the database before connecting , the very first thing you do is create the connection and connect you can't request before that or you will get an error:

```
public static Connection connection= null;

    public static void openConnection(){

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //you call the mysql driver so it gets loaded
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection(URL_CONEXION, USER, PASSWORD); //you actually connect to the DataBase
            if (connection!=null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connection to:  "+ DATA_BASE + " Successful","Attention",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                //message to show that you are actually connected
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){                
               System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); // You print in console the error
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` does not create the connection, and is not necessary.

Comment: It doesn't create the connection but it does check to see if the class exists.  It's a way to catch an error before actually creating the connection.  No, it's not necessary, but it's good practice.